# How to measure/predict volatility of a time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, volatility-forecasting

Here's the problem:

We have an entity, and entity can switch ownership. The data can be seen as a time series of events (i.e. ownership change). Of course, events are labeled with epoch time.

So intuitively, we have two features that can help us measure volatility. That is,

- number of changes over time
- the time difference between changes

It is worth mentioning that the time series can be very small (2-3 events) - I'm not dealing with high volumed data here. Also, the time difference between events can be days, months or even few years.

I'm looking for a way to score "how stable is the entity is". Maybe even a way to answer the question: "what's the probability that a new event will occur in X days".

I'd be glad if you could suggest me ideas / directions / relevant reading materials.

Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I would try to attack your problem as rare events study instead of a time series. You may start with a classic as the Poisson process. Then estimate the parameter(s) of the model for different companies and see what happens.